# PL/SQL Oracle_home directory contents of listener.ora

Tags: oracle, file-io, plsql, oracle11g, home-directory

I'm trying to write the contents of listener.ora to another file without hardcoding in the directory.

Originally it worked when I specified the directory as:

```
'C:\app\OracleDB11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN'
```

But I don't want to hard-code because this script will be used different machines/DBs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY LISTENERDIR AS '%ORACLE_HOME%/NETWORK/ADMIN/';
declare
f utl_file.file_type;
fOUT utl_file.file_type;
s varchar2(200);
begin
f := utl_file.fopen('LISTENERDIR','listener.ora','R');
loop
    utl_file.get_line(f,s);
    fOUT := utl_file.fopen('OUTPUT','oraDBoutput.txt','A');
    utl_file.put_line(fOUT,s);
    utl_file.fclose(fOUT);
end loop;
exception
when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    utl_file.fclose(f);
end;
/

drop directory LISTENERDIR;
```

I have tried using the other slashes, small caps, different variations such as `\NETWORK\ADMIN`, and even assigning a variable from the `dbms_system.get_env()` but no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY LISTENERDIR AS
> ```
>
> '%ORACLE_HOME%/NETWORK/ADMIN/';

We cannot do this. We have to specify the absolute OS path when we create a directory object.  That's why it worked when you used the full path.  It's in the documentation.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm#i2061958).

If you really want to create the library dynamically you can do it like this:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.    

SQL> declare
  2      l_home varchar2(255);
  3  begin
  4      dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', l_home);
  5
  6      execute immediate 'create directory listenerdir as '''
  7          ||l_home||'\NETWORK\ADMIN''';
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> select directory_path
  2  from all_directories
  3  where directory_name = 'LISTENERDIR'
  4  /

DIRECTORY_PATH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\app\oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

SQL>
```

DBMS_SYSTEM.GET_ENV() is guaranteed to return the correct directory for the $ORACLE_HOME used to start the instance; other methods are not.  Only the SYS user has rights on DBMS_SYSTEM by default, but then only the restricted accounts ought to have the CREATE ANY DIRECTORY privilege.

---

Not sure why you are using PL/SQL to do this.  I'm always in favour of using the database to do as much as possible, but this strikes me as an over-elaborate way of executing what is a simple OS copy.

Comment: thanks! It worked. all i had to add was to do spool the content to a file :)

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(file_spec, 1, INSTR(file_spec, '\', -1, 2) -1)
FROM dba_libraries
WHERE library_name = 'DBMS_SUMADV_LIB';
```

Found it [here](http://oraqa.com/2006/02/12/how-to-get-oracle_home-from-data-dictionary/). And [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2206911&tstart=240).

This will programmatically get you the ORACLE_HOME, from there you can create your Oracle directory object:

```
DECLARE
  dir VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY  LISTENERDIR AS '''||
          SUBSTR(file_spec, 1, INSTR(file_spec, '\', -1, 2) -1) ||''''
    INTO dir
    FROM dba_libraries
    WHERE library_name = 'DBMS_SUMADV_LIB';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dir;
   ... do your stuff here...
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP DIRECTORY LISTENERDIR';
END;
/
```

Comment: Both the links you give point out that this is not necessarily the actual Oracle Home (especially on XP).

Comment: True, but it was the only thing I could find that might help. Plus, I'd never heard of dba_libraries before, so it was a useful exercise ;-)